# C# runas not workging same as real user

Tags: c#, runas

I have two user: one admin, one power user (On Win10 Pro 64)
I've disable UAC.

If I run the test with the manual right click, and set the power user credential, all work fine.
If I run the test with my C# application the test doesn't work.
I've got an : Access was denied while trying to open files in your profile directory.
The test is .cmd that run Firefox selenium gecko driver. But is not the point here.

It's seem runas have a different behavior when it was called by C# rather than real user.

Is there anything to do to be sure that Process runas do the same think that real user ?

I've tried all the flag combinaison and and default folder !

Thanks in advance.

```
// Main process
oProcStart = new Process();

oProcStart.StartInfo.FileName = "c:\\tests\\test.cmd";
oProcStart.StartInfo.Arguments = String.empty;
// I Try all paths that I can
oProcStart.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = String.empty;
oProcStart.StartInfo.WindowStyle = oParamIn.eStyle;

oParamIn.oCred.GetDomainUserPwd(out String sDomain, out String sUser, out String sPwd);
oProcStart.StartInfo.Domain          = sDomain;
oProcStart.StartInfo.UserName        = sUser;
oProcStart.StartInfo.Password        = sPwd.ToSecureString();
oProcStart.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
oProcStart.StartInfo.Verb            = "runas";

oProcStart.StartInfo.WindowStyle     = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
oProcStart.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow  = true;
oProcStart.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

oProcStart.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
oProcStart.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError  = true;

oProcStart.EnableRaisingEvents              = true;

// On ouput recevived
oProcStart.OutputDataReceived += (object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs e) =>
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e?.Data))
        oOutData.Append(e.Data + "\n");

};

// On error recevived
oProcStart.ErrorDataReceived += (object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs e) =>
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e?.Data))
        oOutErr.Append(e.Data + "\n");
};
// Start it
oProcStart.Start();
```

Comment: Just to be clear, is the user the same each time you run?

Comment: Yes. . . . . . .